# Will onStart be called before child activity finishes?

Tags: android, android-activity

According to [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), if an activity calls `startActivityForResult` from within `onCreate` with a non-negative request code, the activity will not be shown until the child activity returns a result. It's clear from the docs that `onActivityResult` will be called just before `onResume` (which implies that `onResume` will never be called before the child activity returns). However, I can't find anything about whether `onStart` will be called immediately after `onCreate` returns (without waiting for the child activity to return) or whether all lifecycle events after `onCreate` are suspended until the child activity returns when `startActivityForResult` is called from within `onCreate`.

Does anyone know what the behavior is and whether it is specified anywhere?

Comment: I don't know the specifics, but it should be very easy to test..
Setup an activity that starts another activity for result in the onCreate, and in onStart override it with a Log.e("firstActivity", "onStart called");+super.onStart.
And then see when the onStart event fires...

Comment: @Anders - Yes, I can run a test and determine how it works on one or a few devices under whatever test scenario(s) I use. The important issue is whether the behavior will be consistent across devices and API levels (including future ones). If the behavior is specified (that is, documented), then a test makes sense. If it is undefined, then it seems to me that running a test is pretty useless.